# Populate angular filter from JS function doesnt trigger the filter to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am not sure if what I am doing is the right angular way of doing it, I have the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manzanofab/5adnd51L/3/)
that displays on a repeat the rows from a query result.

Javascript:

```
function updateSearch(search) {
    console.log(search);
    document.getElementById('searchFor').value = search;
}

function ExampleController($scope) {
    $scope.profiles = [{
        Company_Name__c: 'John & Co',
        Events_per_year__c: '1-4',
        Delegates_Each_Year__c: '10-50',
        Type_of_Events__c: 'Corporate event'
    }, {
        Company_Name__c: 'Maritis',
        Events_per_year__c: '5-10',
        Delegates_Each_Year__c: '151-300',
        Type_of_Events__c: 'Association'
    }, {
        Company_Name__c: 'Mike & Co',
        Events_per_year__c: '5-10',
        Delegates_Each_Year__c: '1000+',
        Type_of_Events__c: 'Corporate event'
    }, {
        Company_Name__c: 'Adam & Co',
        Events_per_year__c: '5-10',
        Delegates_Each_Year__c: '151-300',
        Type_of_Events__c: 'Association'
    }, {
        Company_Name__c: 'Juliesss',
        Events_per_year__c: '5-10',
        Delegates_Each_Year__c: '301-500',
        Type_of_Events__c: 'Team building'
    }, {
        Company_Name__c: 'Juliet',
        Events_per_year__c: '20+',
        Delegates_Each_Year__c: '301-500',
        Type_of_Events__c: 'Association'
    }];
}

angular.module('searchProfile',[]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng:app="searchProfile"><div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <input id="searchFor" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <select id="numberEvents" class="form-control" onchange="updateSearch(this.value)">
                    <option value="">What is the average number of delegates that attend each year</option>
                    <option value="10-50">10-50</option>
                    <option value="51-150">51-150</option>
                    <option value="151-300">151-300</option>
                    <option value="301-500">301-500</option>
                    <option value="501-800">501-800</option>
                    <option value="1000+">1000+</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <select id="delegates" class="form-control" onchange="updateSearch(this.value)">
                    <option value="">How many events do you organise each year</option>
                    <option value="1-4">1-4</option>
                    <option value="5-10">5-10</option>
                    <option value="11-15">11-15</option>
                    <option value="16-20">16-20</option>
                    <option value="20+">20+</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <select id="delegates" class="form-control" onchange="updateSearch(this.value)">
                    <option value="">What type of events</option>
                    <option value="Small meeting">Small meeting</option>
                    <option value="Conference">Conference</option>
                    <option value="Association">Association</option>
                    <option value="Corporate event">Corporate event</option>
                    <option value="Incentive and reward groups">Incentive and reward groups</option>
                    <option value="Team building">Team building</option>
                    <option value="Exhibitions">Exhibitions</option>
                    <option value="Large trade shows and events">Large trade shows and events</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table id="searchTextResults" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr class="success">
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Events</th>
                <th>Delegates</th>
                <th>Type of Events</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in profiles | filter:search">
                <td><span>{{i.Company_Name__c}}</span>
                </td>
                <td>{{i.Events_per_year__c}}</td>
                <td>{{i.Delegates_Each_Year__c}}</td>
                <td>{{i.Type_of_Events__c}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I have a filter in it, that works fine. However I have some dropdowns that when change it updates the filter with the option selected. Unfortunately when the filter is changed due to this action, the table is not filter, I have to delete the last word in order to take place.

The images below illustrates better what it is happening

when dropdown change it populates the original input for search

[image: when dropdown change it populates the original input for search]

After deleting last "word" in this case a zero the table got filtered

[image: After deleting last "word" in this case a zero the table got filtered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked and updated your fiddle so it is now working:
http://jsfiddle.net/2gmn11os/

The issue you were having is that the "onchange" event was making changes to variables inside your scope *outside* of Angulars digest cycle. This is why you saw the updates be applied only when you changed the input field directly - those changes are processed through the ng-model directive which kicks off the cycle and re-applies filters, etc.

You want your 'selects' to read a bit more like this, so that changes to their state are part of the Angular cycle:

```
<select id="numberEvents" ng-model="events" class="form-control" ng-change="updateSearch(events)">
```

I also shifted the code around so it's a bit tidier too, instead of having that function on the global scope outside of your app structure :)